# Loading Clojure Leiningen projects in Eclipse

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Clojure/Leiningen/Eclipse (and Java) newby. I'm trying to get Eclipse to load a Clojure/Leiningen project, and I'm seeing confusing/contradictory results searching for Lein plugin solutions.

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426
(Windows 8)

I've got the following user profile in .lein\profiles.clj

```
{:user {:plugins [ [lein-eclipse "1.0.0"]
]}}
```

And the following Leiningen project file:

```
(defproject firstclojureproj "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [
                [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                [lein-eclipse "1.0.0"]
                ]
)
```

Doing a lein help I get the following (which I think is the root of my problem)

```
leiningen.eclipse  Problem loading: Could not locate clojure/contrib/duck_streams__init.class or clojure/contrib/duck_streams.clj on classpath:
```

Also when I attempt to Import / Existing Projects into Workspace / and select the folder with my Leiningen project, the folder appears grayed-out with a check box and I cannot select it.

Comment: Please check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127021/how-to-open-existing-clojure-project-in-eclipse/30951233#30951233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lein-eclipse plugin is a plugin to leiningen that produces eclipse project files. It goes in the :plugins section of the project.clj file.

```
:plugins [[lein-eclipse "x.y.z"]]
```

(assuming you are using lein 2.1.x+)

lein-eclipse "1.0.0" is hopelessly old (3 years) and won't work with a modern version of leiningen. There is a "2.0.0" version on [clojars](https://clojars.org/repo/lein2-eclipse/lein2-eclipse/) though I have not looked into it enough to know if it works better.

Comment: Actually it's 
[no-man-is-an-island/lein-eclipse "2.0.0"]
lein eclipse now built .project and .classpath, loaded into Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for a special plugin.

Create a Maven pom-file:

```
→ lein pom
Wrote /home/jhoetzel/clojure/hellop/pom.xml
```

Use the Maven eclipse:eclipse goal to generate the Eclipse configuration files:

```
→ mvn eclipse:eclipse
[INFO] Wrote Eclipse project for "hellop" to /home/juergen/clojure/hellop.
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `[no-man-is-an-island/lein-eclipse "2.0.0"]` to your `project.clj` under `:plugins`. Then run:

```
>lein deps
>lein eclipse
```

Output should be:

```
Created .classpath
Created .project
```

You can now import your project folder as an "Existing project into workspace" in Eclipse (Counterclockwise).