# How to open existing Clojure project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, clojure, leiningen

Ive tried to do it usual way File -> Import -> General -> Existing project (as for java projects) BUT eclipse dont see clojure projects and cannot open it :(
do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 11):

1. Install [Counterclockwise](http://doc.ccw-ide.org/documentation.html) plugin in Eclipse (from eclipse marketplace). This brings clojure and leiningen support to eclipse.
2. Add [lein2-eclipse](https://github.com/netmelody/lein2-eclipse) plugin to your project.clj :

   :plugins [[lein2-eclipse "2.0.0"]]
3. Run following command inside the project directory :

   lein eclipse

This generates necessary project files.

4. Import the project into eclipse ( File -> Import -> General -> Existing project ).
5. Right click on the project in eclipse then "Configure > Convert to leiningen project"

Answer (score 1):

You need a plugin for a Clojure project in Eclipse. Check [Counterclockwise](http://doc.ccw-ide.org/documentation.html#_install_counterclockwise).

Although I personally use Counterclockwise, I think there are better IDEs for Clojure than Eclipse, for example [LightTable](http://www.lighttable.com/).

Comment: installed Counterclockwise via marketplace , but Eclipse still says " No projects are found to import"

Comment: If it's not an eclipse project (but just a lein project) yet you'll have to first create a Clojure Eclipse project and then import the content of the original project in it.